# Installed ubuntu 13.04. Later format windows 7 from recovery partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, data-recovery

tried formatting windows 7 from recovery partition - it needs to reboot several times in this process.  but after the first im now im stuck on 
"error: no such partition.
grub rescue"

worst yet:
im on a netbook with no dvd/cd drive!

i created another bootable usb for ubuntu 13.04 with my wife's computer and it still says the same as above.

now i have no drivers installed (thankfully the usb drive is found), and i cant load anything :( im afraid ubuntu has ruined my recovery partition and now my wife is going smash my balls since her computer wont boot up now either... it says "operating system not found." so i had to write this on a damn iphone.  anyways, hers wont be a problem bc of a bootable disk drive.

is there any commands to enter on this ubuntu screen of death?  can i, and if so, how do i access the recovery partition?? or remove this boot to ubuntu BS that is ruining my life at the moment?!?  please help!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu did not ruin your recovery partition, but your Master Boot Record is messed up. Basically, when you formatted Windows, you also formatted your whole computer. Windows did not think to update the MBR, so your computer still thinks it needs to use GRUB as a bootloader. Here's what you can do to fix that:

1. Boot into a Windows Recovery Disk
2. Choose to use the Recovery Console
3. Type `fixmbr`, then type <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Reboot when finished
5. Profit! You can now boot into Windows!